# Open a .txt file using Pandas but all the data came into one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database, dataframe

I need to open a `.txt` file using pandas by using the command below, but when it opens, all of a the data is in one column instead of the 24 that I expected. What am I doing wrong?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\\\Escritorio\\basedeu\\deudores.txt", sep="\t", header=None)

print(type(df))
```

Comment: Are you using the correct separator for the file?

Comment: Can you include a sample of your `.txt` file?

Comment: Looking deeper into the data, i noticed that the data in the .txt is all the raw together(there is no separation between the features), so the problen here is how to split the data using some funtion included in Pandas?. leave an example below

1120117694233199906 this should be 4 different columns

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the separator in your file is not a tab ('\t'). On my system I tried creating a tab-delimited text file using my Pycharm editor like this:

```
aaa bbb ccc
ddd eee fff
ggg hhh iii
```

When using pandas.read_csv(), it turns out the correct delimiter is a whitespace (" ").